# Total least squares estimator

Tags: r, regression, total-least-squares

In the paper [Ivan Markovsky, Sabine Van Huffel - Overview of Total Least Squares Methods](https://people.duke.edu/%7Ehpgavin/systemid/References/Markovsky+VanHuffel-SP-2007.pdf), at the top of the sixth page, it is claimed that the estimate of $\beta$ in the total least squares model $y \approx A\beta$ is
$$
{(A^TA - \sigma^2I)}^{-1}A^Ty
$$
where $\sigma$ is the smaller singular value of $(A\quad y)$. Applying this formula with R, I don't find the correct result.

```
set.seed(666)
xtilde <- sqrt(1:100)
x <- rnorm(100) + xtilde
y <- rnorm(100) + xtilde

library(pracma)
odregress(x, y)$coef # correct result (I got it with other methods)
# [1]  1.0391737 -0.2865435

A <- model.matrix(~ x)
SVD <- svd(cbind(A, y))
sigma2 <- tail(SVD$d, 1)^2
solve(crossprod(A) - sigma2 * diag(2)) %*% t(A) %*% y
# (Intercept) 21.401578
# x           -1.831176
```

Is there an error in the formula, or am I doing something wrong?

---

## EDIT

One gets the correct slope if we apply this formula after centering $x$ and $y$:

```
xc <- x - mean(x)
yc <- y - mean(y)
A <- model.matrix(~ xc)
SVD <- svd(cbind(A, yc))
sigma2 <- tail(SVD$d, 1)^2
solve(crossprod(A) - sigma2 * diag(2)) %*% t(A) %*% yc
# (Intercept) 2.109424e-15
# xc          1.039174e+00
```

And then one can get the intercept $\bar y - \textrm{slope}\times \bar{x}$.

Comment: Why are you *squaring* $\sigma^2$ in your last calculation??

Comment: @whuber Because I apply the formula as it is given.

Comment: I don't square $\sigma^2$.

Comment: `tail(SVD$d, 1)^2` squares it.

Comment: Yes, this is the formula, there's a square. And now I checked that the general formula gives the same result.

Comment: I get the correct slope if I center $x$ and $y$.